# Can pLSA model generate topic distribution of unseen documents?

Tags: topic-models, latent-semantic-analysis

I refer to the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_latent_semantic_analysis) and other tutorials on topic modeling, which said

> although PLSA is a generative model of the documents in the collection it is estimated on, it is not a generative model of new documents.

while another [tutorial](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~nasmith/LS2/gimpel.06.pdf) page 15 that illustrates pLSA and LDA in geometric way said

> The pLSI model allows a document to possess a distribution over topics that was seen in the training data, thus placing new documents at particular points within the topic simplex.

Could I and should I use a trained pLSA model to generate topic distributions on unseen (new) documents?

Answer (score 1):

pLSA learns the topics from the training set(fitting the model). pLSA doesn't predict new topics from unseen data. it just uses the topics learned during training and returns the  document-topic distribution for your unseen test set(transform).

Comment: The Wiki says that LDA has overcome the shortcoming of pLSA which is not a generative model for new document. So does it mean that LDA can learn a new generative model on a new document?